# How To Create PK As I need My Code Attached SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, primary-key

I am trying to create PK as `CP-00001` but my code is creating PK as `INV-19072013-0001` in my stored procedure I need to create like `CP-00001` if no row exist other wise it increment in previous id and then id become `CP-00002`

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_AutoGenerateInoviceNumber] 
AS 
   Declare @InvNumberDate varchar(15) 

   Select @InvNumberDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105),'-','') 

   Declare @NewNumber varchar(20)

   If Exists (Select 1 from tbl_InvoiceMaster Where InvoiceNo LIKE '%'+ @InvNumberDate +'%') 
   Begin
       Select Top 1 @NewNumber = InvoiceNo 
       from tbl_InvoiceMaster 
       Where InvoiceNo LIKE '%'+ @InvNumberDate +'%'
       order by ROW_ID desc 

       Declare @NewSerialNo varchar(10) 
       Set @NewSerialNo = SUBSTRING(@NewNumber, CHARINDEX('-',@NewNumber, 5) + 1, LEN(@NewNumber))    
       Set @NewNumber = SUBSTRING(@NewNumber, 0, CHARINDEX('-',@NewNumber, 5))   

       Select @NewNumber = @NewNumber + '-' + dbo.func_IncrementNumber(@NewSerialNo)  
   End
Else
  Set @NewNumber = 'INV-'+@InvNumberDate+'-0001'
Select @NewNumber
```

Hopes for your suggestion thanks

Comment: reason for down voting ?

Comment: Why do you need the PK to be "CP-00001"? Make the PK an auto-increment and add all the "CP-0" stuff in a view.

Comment: yup i am willing the same as you mentioned how would it can be achieve :(

Comment: Your question isn't clear.   I don't see anywhere where you are applying a 'CP-' prefix.  Also, you say you want the 'INV-' prefix if no row exists, except you're using `IF EXISTS()` instead of `IF NOT EXISTS()`

Comment: i made it clear mate please up vote question now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the identity property on you PK and add the business logic for "CP-" in a view.

More details on indentiy can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)